# Проверка на не пустой input

Tags: css3, css

Есть несколько `input type="text"` в форме

нужно чтобы когда поле пустое - один фоновой цвет, а когда заполнено хотя бы одним символом - другой цвет.
Пробую так:

```
.block input
{
    outline: none;
    background-color: #9ed6a3;
}

.block input:not(:empty) 
{
    outline: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

`:not(:empty)` работать не хочет, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

в `css3/html5` есть `invalid/required` http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Mc72q/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" required />
<input type="text" required />    
<input type="text" required />
```

CSS:

```
input:invalid {
    background-color: red;
}
```

описание

насчет `:empty` - `input` всегда `empty`,медитировать на

```
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: сейчас ещё есть https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown - немного проще